# How to validate a content in URL (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, url, null, validation

I have URLs in JSON feed n each URL contains one image. I want to validate those URLs which have image or not (NULL). How to validate this using  javascript.
         since I'm a beginner, i don't know, how to validate this. thanks

```
      JSON feed with image n NULL
        {

         previewImage:"http://123.201.137.238:6060/feed/videoplay/Jackie.png",

        }, 
        {

        previewImage:"http://www.snovabits.net/feed/ImageMI/WarCraft.jpg",

        },
```

Comment: Can you post sample json, preferably with links accessible to others. Also, post the code that you have written/tried so far.

Comment: You cannot do this with JavaScript alone unless all of the images are hosted on the same domain as your JavaScript.  Is this the case?

Comment: Is there Any other way? to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

Try to add the images to a div (use jQuery, the div can be hidden using *display:none;*).
Then test the properties of the images regularly (use a *setInterval* loop) whether they indicate a successful load. Define some timeout after which the setInterval will kill itself.

This property works for testing successful img load in Chrome and Firefox:

```
naturalHeight != 0
```

This property works for testing successful img load in IE7,8,9:

```
fileCreatedDate != ''
```

Test both to make it work in all major browsers.

Here is a fiddle to see how the props change in 10ms steps during the load process. Try it in different browsers!:
http://jsfiddle.net/xGmdP/

In Chrome and FF you can even replace the timeout for the setInterval loop by checking the *complete* property of all images. But unfortunately this does not work in IE (*complete* always stays false in IE for images that cannot be loaded).

Finally here is the complete code of the fiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(function(){
      $('#images').prepend('<img id="img1" src="http://123.201.137.238:6060/feed/videoplay/Jackie.png">')
      $('#images').prepend('<img id="img2" src="http://www.snovabits.net/feed/ImageMI/WarCraft.jpg">')
      setInterval(test, 10);
    })

    function test(){
      var props=['naturalHeight', 'complete', 'fileCreatedDate', 'clientHeight', 'offsetHeight', 'nameProp', 'sourceIndex'];
      for(i in props){
        var pr = props[i];
        $('#testresults').append('1:'+pr+' = ' + $('#img1').prop(pr)+'<br>');
        $('#testresults').append('2:'+pr+' = ' + $('#img2').prop(pr)+'<br>');
      }
      $('#testresults').append('---<br>');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images"><div>
  <div id="testresults"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOw! Great! I Exactly Expect this answer. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the string is null just do `if(previewImage == "") { /* image is null, do stuff */ }` but if you want to check if the image actually exists I would suggest doing a GET request via AJAX and check the HTTP response, e.g: (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://123.201.137.238:6060/feed/videoplay/Jackie.png",
    cache: false,
    error: function(){
       alert("image doesn't exist!");
    }
});
```

But it would be "nicer" to do this server side if possible.

Comment: Great idea, but doesn't work for me. Alert is triggered although the image exists.